# under what circumstances do browsers refuse to continue calling setInterval callbacks?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I'm dealing with a difficult bug where a setInterval callback only gets called 20 or 21 times and then never again, even though I never cleared the interval.  (running in Chrome at least)

The page remains responsive, so the callback is not getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Do browsers decide to stop calling a setInterval callback if it takes too long to execute?  For instance if some expensive canvas drawing is performed in the setInterval callback?

Unfortunately there are too many potentially-involved layers in this issue (i.e. React, Redux, custom Redux middleware, Canvas drawing) to post a good code sample here.  I am asking about the **expected behavior** of setInterval in modern browsers.

**EDIT** I think I may be seeing a bug in Chrome to do with canvas drawing inside of `setInterval`/`setTimeout`.  I can't reproduce in Firefox.

Comment: How've you verified the interval is not recalled? Can you provide a link, where we could see and examine this presumed failure?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is in a private pre-release product.

Comment: Even my CSS transitions appear to stop working once the interval dies.  I think I may be dealing with a bug in Chrome here.

Comment: It's hard to debug a code you can't see ...

Comment: Can't I just ask if someone knows cases in which browsers deliberately kill an interval instead of everyone thinking there's something wrong with my code?

Comment: Andy, calm down. I answered your question and you said "this isn't the issue". You're asking what is the issue or cases in which browsers deliberately kill an interval?

Comment: The expected behavior is, that an interval will be executed, if something blocks the execution, interval calls are cumulated, and when possible again, the cumulated calls are executed as fast as possible.

Comment: Yes...sorry, I get tired of people on SO taking the attitude of "no code, no answer."  If as far as you know browsers should never be able to kill the interval altogether, that's the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that's about it... browser don't seem to kill the interval (they sometimes cap it to 1 call per second, as I said, but there seem to be no case in which they stop)

Comment: Right, I've seen that in MDN documentation but nothing about it stopping permanently.  That's the other reason I'm frustrated...the browser just doesn't seem to be behaving the way it should.

Comment: If I can manager to come up with minimal repro code I'll post it, and if I can get a bug report filed and accepted, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @Andy Sorry for the inconvinience, but far too often questions like this end up to something like: "An error prevented to show results on a page" or "Oops, conflicting variable name did clear the interval" etc. That's why we want to see the code. Questions can definitely be asked without an example code, but in that case you have to describe the problem really well, and answer all the questions  asked in the comments ...

Comment: @Teemu if I could get it down to a short repro scenario with no private code, I'd definitely post it, but as I said, there is just too much code involved to fit here, each setInterval callback is dispatching redux actions that cause a deep React component hierarchy to update, if I posted all of that code it would probably be 10,000 lines.

Comment: I made an effort to rule out things like accidental clearInterval calls (by monkeypatching and logging each time it gets called), infinite loops, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) documentation, the only mention of "variation" from the standard behavior seems to be:

> Starting in Gecko 5.0 (Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2), intervals are clamped to fire no more often than once per second in inactive tabs.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the issue.  The tab is active.